# Is this a correct translation into Quenya?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, languages, translation

I've translated

*I am free. I am myself (me).*

as

*Nanyë léra, Nanyë immo*

[image]

Based on the fragments I found over at [this](http://quenya101.com/how-do-we-say-in-quenya/) page. Is my translation correct? Can it be improved to better convey the meaning I intend? Note that I'm trying to say I'm now myself (as opposed to pretending to be someone else until now). Also, is the actual tengwar text I have correct?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: Incorporating the suggestion by @JanusBahsJacquet, I've also attempted to translate

*Nanyë léra, Inyë immo*

which, hopefully means the same as my original intention above but adds a little alliteration to the phrase. Here is my final tengwar, along with the corrections provided so kindly by @bobby-newmark.

[image: Nanyë léra, Inyë immo]

Comment: I found this site to be an excellent Quenya reference. There is even a .pdf course that covers Quenya word creation. I know it's ugly, but the information is fantastic. http://folk.uib.no/hnohf/

Comment: According to Ardalambion (the link in Bobby’s comment above), copular sentences in Quenya do not necessarily require an actual copula—you can also construct them as in Russian, by having just the subject and the predicate. If you want some alliteration in your second sentence, you could use the emphatic independent 1sg. pronoun alone with the reflexive: ***inye immo*** should mean the same as _nanyë immo_.

Comment: Thanks @JanusBahsJacquet - would you have the actual Quenya (Tengwar font characters) for this word? Also, please make this an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm hesitant to post it as an answer, because I simply don't know enough about Quenya to stand by it as fact. There is an awful lot of information about Quenya on Ardalambion, and I only skimmed through tiny bits of it to find something about the copula and the reflexive pronoun. The copula has a whole section (though it's under-attested and a bit sketchy), but I couldn't find anything about the reflexive pronoun at all, except a lot of quite significantly divergent forms (depending, it seems, on both person and case) in example writings…

Comment: @ananthonline, I read all the course material a couple of months ago, and word formation in Quenya is REALLY complicated. Depending on the "stem" of the word, different suffixes and suffix forms are added to indicate both tense and ownership. "I am free" is probably formed something like "free+present tense suffix of to be + pronomial suffix of I".  I wouldn't feel comfortable giving an answer with out a lot more research.

Comment: Sorry about so many comments...@ananthonline, that actually looks great. From what I can tell, your Quenya translation is spot on.  I'll try to put an answer together with references.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like your translation is spot on.

This answer is based on the site [Ardalambion](http://folk.uib.no/hnohf/) .

In translating "I am free. I am myself.", the tricky part was "*I am*".  It appears to be one word, "**Nanyë**". I found this explanation for the word:

> With pronominal endings this verb may appear as násë "he/she is", nás "it is"; 
>   **otherwise the regular pronominal endings are added to na-** (**nanyë "I
>   am"**, nalyë "you are" etc.; see full list of pronominal suffixes
>   below). The past tense "was, were" would be similar, only with the
>   vowels e, é where the present tense has a, á: hence nenyë "I was",
>   nelyë "you were" etc.

[Reference](http://folk.uib.no/hnohf/quenya.htm) Bold mine

Which is about as clear as mud. However, what it mean is this: **na-** is the present tense "*to be*" verb, and by adding the suffix **-nyë** (which is the pronomial suffix for "*I*") you make the new word **nanyë** which means "I am". (In Quenya, "*I*" is rarely an independent pronoun. "*I am*" would look like "*amI*", as one word.) (And yeah, it's weird, but I guess J.R.R. really liked Finnish.)

So, the first word is correct.

The second word and the fourth word are both in this [dictionary](http://www.ambar-eldaron.com/eng-quen.pdf).

The second word "free" is in bold:

> FREE (adj.) **léra**, aranya (not to be confused with aranya *"my king";
>   the shorter form ranya also cited must not be confused with the verb
>   "stray, wander"),

The third word "myself" is in bold

> MYSELF (reflexive pronoun) **immo** (a general sg. reflexive pronoun,
>   covering English "myself, him/herself, yourself").

The third word is the first word again.

I think "*I am free. I am myself*." is "**Nanyë léra, Nanyë immo**" in Quenya.

**Second Part!**

The Tengwar translation, is great, but there are a few things I think you should check.  I am using this [chart](http://quenya101.com/elvish-course/tengwar-alphabet/#Guide) and these [rules](http://quenya101.com/elvish-course/tengwar-alphabet/#TengwarChart).

**First word, "Nanyë":**  Everything seems correct.

**Second word, "léra":** Wow, you got that the long e needed a carrier!  That's amazing!

However, the last letter is "a".  The vowel symble over the "r" character (looks like a long y) is a slash, which is "e".  It should be three dots, which is "a".

**Third word, "Nanyë":**  Should be the same as the first word, but the vowel symbols are missing on the last character.

**Fourth word, "immo":** Great job getting the line under the "m" to make it a double consonant.  But the "o" after the double "m" is not indicated.  There should be a crescent mark above the double character to show the "o".

OK...now that I'm at work, here's how I think the Tengwar should look:

[image]

Yep...your new edit is spot on.  Short carrier for the initial "*i*" and the "*n*" carrying the "*y*" and the "*e*".

I hope that is helpful!

Comment: I don't think there's anything at all weird about a language that adds suffixes instead of using separate words for everything, but then my first language was Hungarian, so what do I know. :)

Comment: @Martha There isn't. English used to do it as well, till we got too lazy (and still does a tiny bit). Other languages that do the same are Spanish, Italian, Portuguese, French, German, Dutch, Irish, Welsh, Icelandic, Russian, Polish, Greek, as well as pretty much every Native American language out there—so basically every language that English is surrounded by, more or less. It's exceedingly common, cross-linguistically.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. Thanks for putting in the work and explaining it all so well. As @JanusBahsJacquet suggested, I'm also considering the variation - Nanyë léra, Inyë immo for alliteration. I'll edit my question shortly and attempt my translation for that, too. I'd be most grateful for any comments you have about it.

Comment: @ananthonline, thanks!

Comment: "Inyë" works, too.  It's "emphatic".  Let's see the Tengwar!